# Inequality constraint for using ADMM algorithm

Tags: convex-optimization

I'm trying to express the following constrained optimization problem:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{x}{\text{minimize}}
& & \| b - x \|_1 + \lambda \| \mathbf{D}x \|_2 \\
& \text{subject to}
& & x \leq b \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Where $\mathbf{D}$ is a finite-difference matrix and $b$ is some observed data.

I want to use ADMM, which handles only equality constraint. From reading round, I learned that you can convert it into an inequality constraint by imposing a non-negativity constraint on $-x + b$:

$
0 \leq -x + b
$

I've re-formulated the problem to now become:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{x}{\text{minimize}}
& & \| z_1 \|_1 + \lambda \| z_2 \|_2 + I_{C}(z_3)\\
& \text{subject to}
&  -x + b &= z_1 \\
&  & \mathbf{D}x &= z_2\\
&  & -x + b &= z_3
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Where the $I_C(z_3)$ is an indicator function to impose non-negative constraint on $z_3$. But somehow this looks 'wrong' because I don't know if it's legitimate to define the same auxilliary variable twice in the constraint.... What is the correct way to re-formulate the original problem so that I can use ADMM?